# How to remove added spacing when using ::first-letter on a button?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am seeing extra spacing added to buttons that use some `::first-letter` styles. This appears to be browser-specific, because it is happening for me in Firefox (74 & 63) but not Chrome and Safari.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .caps button::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <button>foo bar</button>
  <br/>
  <button>much longer button label text</button>
</div>

<div class="caps">
  <button>foo bar</button>
  <br/>
  <button>much longer button label text</button>
</div>
```

`text-transform` and `font-size` add spacing, but `color` does not. I'm sure there are other styles that affect this as well.

And buttons with longer text content get proportionally more extra spacing. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0x2b3op/) for a couple examples.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a best practice to remove the added spacing? It looks like `display: inline-flex` does the trick, but I'm not sure that's the best route.